# Grails get stuck at "finished configuring Spring Security REST"

Tags: grails

I type `grails run-app` and it begins to run, but it gets stuck on the message:

```
----------------------------------------
Current config:
baseDir: db/migration/global
env: DEVELOPMENT
dataSource: default
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydbapp
username: postgres
schemas: public
----------------------------------------
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Configuring Spring Security REST ...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST
```

It used to run fine like an hour ago. No strange logs or anything. Also, when hit `ctrl+c` in the terminal, grails will close, but when I `run-app` again, it will say something like:

```
Error Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Indicating that grails wasn't really terminated. Of course, I kill the app occupying `8080` and run-app again, but it's still getting stuck.

Comment: Did you try to reboot your IDE/machine? I used to have weird problems with IDE or JVM.

Comment: Which version Grails and JDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The port 8080 is been used for another thread. Try to find a java thread in your system that you don't recognize and stop it.

How to on [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

How to on [Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-out-what-ports-are-listeningopen-on-my-linuxfreebsd-server/)

Comment: He wrote: `Of course, I kill the app occupying 8080 and run-app again, but it's still getting stuck.`

Answer (score 0):

In BuildConfig.groovy, change your apps port. Example:

```
grails.server.port.http = 8003
```

If you still get port in use, exit IntelliJ, goto Task Manager, sort by memory used, end any processes with IntelliJ or Grails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using liquibase database migration tool and if you somehow stopped it before it finishes it will put a lock at DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table. Change it to LOCKED = false and it will start.